# How to add space in text of the equation Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, equation

I want to write an equation in Jupyter notebook's markdown cell which contains text with space. I tried writing the following.

```
\begin{equation*}
e^{i\pi} + 1 + some text = 0
\end{equation*}
```

Which results like this.

[image]

How to add space between "some" and "text"? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try wrapping your text in `\text{}`.

```
\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi} + 1 + \text{some text} = 0
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Note: this is more of a latex question, to which you can get answers from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you could consider " \ " and "\quad" directives to add horizontal space between elements in a LaTeX environment, also "\hskip".